# Rewrite URL in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to do a rewrite in .htaccess.
User who stay at http://mydomain.com/article_name#number it's same to be in http://mydomain.com/article?var1=number&var2=number&var3=number.
How can i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it

```
RewriteRule ^/article_name#(\d+)$ /article?var1=$1&var2=$1&var3=$1  [NC]
```

Comment: Dont' work. I read that the values after hash(#) doesn't sent to server. Is it possible ?

Comment: how do the values after the # look like?

Comment: Is there any other rewrite rule that could take precedence over this one?